# Class name change when creating WCF Proxy

Tags: .net, wcf

I have created a WCF service which return type of `JsonOutput<List<InstallerRequestModel>>`. My JsonOutput is a generic class which accepts any type

```
   public class JsonOutput<T> where T : new()
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public T Result { get; set; }
    }
```

**Service Endpoint**

```
  [OperationContract]
        JsonOutput<List<InstallerRequestModel>> GetInstallerRequests(string requestType);
```

**Installer Request Model**

```
 public class InstallerRequestModel
    {
       [Key]
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Project { get; set; }
       public string ProductVersion { get; set; }
       public string ProductType { get; set; }
       public string PackageType { get; set; }
       public string NeedOfInstaller { get; set; }
       public string Label { get; set; }
       public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
       public string ResourceName { get; set; }
       public string RequestedBy { get; set; }
       public string BuildEngineer { get; set; }
       public string BuildPath { get; set; }
       public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
       public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
       public string BuildStatus { get; set; }
       public string ApprovedBy { get; set; }
       public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
       public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    }
```

the problem after creating by proxy `JsonOutput<List<InstallerRequestModel>>` change to `JsonOutputOfArrayOfInstallerRequestModelohl1y18V`.

```
 public JsonOutputOfArrayOfInstallerRequestModelohl1y18V GetInstallerRequests(string requestType)
        {
            using (var buildPortalServiceClient = new BuildPortalServiceClient())
            {
                return buildPortalServiceClient.GetInstallerRequests(requestType);
            }
        }
```

I got the result exactly i am expected.But How can i keep the same class name?

Comment: Use `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` for collections and reuse types from referenced assemblies.

Comment: i already select System.Collections.Generic.List when creating proxy.but still the problem exists.

Comment: I have no option of type List<T> in collection type dropdown.only have the type List

Comment: i think the problem is because of JsonOutput<T> class

Comment: WCF exchange messages in XML format, and to serialize types to XMK it has to be of known types, and that does not work with generic types..

Comment: @JohnSaunders i am trying to create the proxy from my local machine.So it have access.

Comment: @MeNoTalk in contract we are specifying the type we want.then why WCF can't implement that generic type in proxy? So are you saying we should follow with Automatically  generated class?

Comment: @JohnSaunders. Yes.I have generated proxy by adding service reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is to share your service contract and data contract classes with the client project.

I created a new project from the "WCF Service Library" template in Visual Studio. I added your `JsonOutput<T>` and `InstallerRequestModel` classes to it, and added your operation contract to the `IService1` service contract. I implemented a dummy `GetInstallerRequests` operation in the `Service1` class so that it would still build.

I took a web application project I had sitting around and added the WCF Service Library to it as a reference (note: not a service reference). This gave that project access to the actual types used in the actual service contract. After getting the WCF Service Library project hosted and starting the host, I was able to add a service reference to the web application. I used the "Advanced" button and made sure that "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" was checked. I confirmed that the referenced library was one of those assemblies. I then clicked OK twice, and Visual Studio created the proxy classes.

Here is one of the methods that it generated. You can see that it references the correct type:

```
public WcfServiceLibrary1.JsonOutput<System.Collections.Generic.List<WcfServiceLibrary1.InstallerRequestModel>>
    GetInstallerRequests(string requestType) {
        return base.Channel.GetInstallerRequests(requestType);
}
```